# Customizing Grub 2 Menu

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

I'm trying to customize the Grub 2 menu.  I have Win 10, Ubuntu, Win 7, Win 95, Win XP on my hard drive.

The Grub Bootloader can see Win 10, Win 7, and Ubuntu.  It does not see the other 2 operating systems.

I can create a sub-menu addition(named Other Windows Systems) but do not know how to direct Grub to the particular partitions.

I searched for command lines but being new to Ubuntu  I don't understand what I need to do.

Thanks for the help. I am on the road and will try your suggestions when I return.

Comment: Grub doesn't actually boot Windows, but rather passes on, aka chainloads, the process to the Windows bootloader, which then takes over and boots the selected version of Windows. I doubt there is very much you can do.

Comment: Grub looks for bootmgr & BCD or ntldr and boot.ini to know Windows boot partition. Windows uses boot flag and all Windows only boot from the one primary NTFS partition with boot flag. If all installs are in primary partitions (would need several drives) then you can move boot flag & run repairs so each install has its own boot files. Then grub can find them.

Answer (score 0):

The grub update command will scan all the connected drives and add all the recognized partitions to the menu.

Run this command:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

As far as customizing grub, you can edit the grub configuration file.  Most of the options documented in the file by comments.

```
$ nano /etc/default/grub
```

After making changes you have to update the boot files with the command above.